# How to auto update the null column imported in the table using apex data loader

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, loader, dataloader

Do you have any idea on how to auto update the table with null column (person_id) after importing the data using the apex data loader? In my csv file template, I do not include the person id, I only include the employee number. And I don't like to include the person id in the csv file template, I want it to be auto updated in case the imported data has null person id.

Answer (score 1):

Two options from me.

Option one - if your database supports it - is to use an **identity column** and let Oracle fill `ID` value:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE so_test
  2  (
  3     id      NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY,
  4     empno   NUMBER,
  5     ename   VARCHAR2 (50)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO so_test (empno, ename) VALUES (1234, 'Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO so_test (id, empno, ename) VALUES (100, 4443, 'Bigfoot');

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM so_test;

        ID      EMPNO ENAME
---------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1       1234 Littlefoot      --> ID created by Oracle
       100       4443 Bigfoot         --> ID inserted manually

SQL> DROP TABLE so_test;

Table dropped.
```

---

Option two is to use **database trigger** (with a **sequence**):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE so_test
  2  (
  3     id      NUMBER,
  4     empno   NUMBER,
  5     ename   VARCHAR2 (50)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE seq_so_test;

Sequence created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_bi_so_test
  2     BEFORE INSERT
  3     ON so_test
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5     WHEN (new.id IS NULL)
  6  BEGIN
  7     :new.id := seq_so_test.NEXTVAL;
  8  END;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL> INSERT INTO so_test (empno, ename) VALUES (1234, 'Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO so_test (id, empno, ename) VALUES (100, 4443, 'Bigfoot');

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM so_test;

        ID      EMPNO ENAME
---------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1       1234 Littlefoot       --> ID created by a trigger
       100       4443 Bigfoot          --> ID inserted manually

SQL> DROP TABLE so_test;

Table dropped.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have a trigger for your table?
If not, create a [trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/statements_7004.htm) and adapt the query of the trigger accordingly such as:

```
IF :NEW.person_id IS NULL THEN
  :NEW.person_id := <sequence_name>.NEXTVAL;
END IF;
```